# Get maximum values within groups but not only the first one (ex æquo as well)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I explain the context: I have an output from Augustus (for 2 species) with a lot of sequences, I made a blast and got cluster of homologous paired sequences, and what I need to do now is to only keep these with the highest identity within each cluster, and even the ex æquo ones.
 For exemple:

I have actually a data frame such:

```
custer     seq 1       seq2        pident    whatever
1           A           B           89          47
1           A           B           89          68
1           C           D           45          90
2           E           F           79          25
2           G           H           89          45
```

......
and what I want to get is something like:

```
custer     seq 1       seq2        pident    whatever
1           A           B           89          47
1           A           B           89          68
2           G           H           89          45
```

I fact, I want to keep the row of the maximum value in the pident column within each cluster, but not only the first one as the following script will do:

```
data_grpd = data.groupby(['cluster'])
result=data.loc[data_grpd['pident'].idxmax()]
```

With that I get:

```
custer     seq 1       seq2        pident    whatever
1           A           B           89          47
2           G           H           89          45
```

In other word, if there is an ex æquo, I want to keep all of them within each cluster.

Does someones could help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) of `max` values per groups with same size as original `DataFrame`,  compare by column `pident` and last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
data_grpd = data.groupby(['cluster'])
result = data.loc[data_grpd['pident'].transform('max') == data['pident']]
print (result)
   cluster seq 1 seq2  pident  whatever
0        1     A    B      89        47
1        1     A    B      89        68
4        2     G    H      89        45
```

**Detail**:

```
print (data_grpd['pident'].transform('max'))
0    89
1    89
2    89
3    89
4    89
Name: pident, dtype: int64
```

EDIT: One possible solution is sorting first:

```
data_wo_eqSpec[['seq1','seq2']] = np.sort(data_wo_eqSpec[['seq1','seq2']], axis=1)

data_grpd = data_wo_eqSpec.groupby(['cluster_name'])
result = data_wo_eqSpec.loc[data_grpd['pident'].transform('max') == data_wo_eqSpec['pident']]
print(result)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help: I'm getting this error:                                      `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cluster_test.py", line 57, in <module>
    result = data.loc[data_grpd['pident'].transform('max') == data['pident']]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 836, in wrapper
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Comment: @Benjamin - What about modification `result = data[data_grpd['pident'].transform(lambda x: x.max() == x)]` ? What is your pandas version?

Comment: My version is pandas  0.22.0 , and now I get: 
    `raise IndexingError('Unalignable boolean Series provided as '
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match`

Comment: @Benjamin - It looks like some typo, how working all on one line like `result = data.loc[data.groupby(['cluster'])['pident'].transform('max') == data['pident']]` or for second 
`result = data[data.groupby(['cluster'])['pident'].transform(lambda x: x.max() == x)]`

Comment: I wrote another commant with my real script, maybe it will be easier for you to understand where is the error

Comment: @Benjamin - I cannot see it.

Comment: @Benjamin - I change edit of my answer, last paragraph. Now it should working nice.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it, using `.apply()`, though it's not as fast as @jezrael's method:

```
(df.groupby('cluster')
 .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.pident == x.pident.max()])
 .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Returns:

```
   cluster seq1 seq2  pident  whatever
0        1    A    B      89        47
1        1    A    B      89        68
2        2    G    H      89        45
```

Comment: It actually works, thanks you :) maybe you have an idea for the next issue I found bellow?

Comment: @Benjamin, you're welcome! As for your next issue, I'd seeing how far you can get if you sort first. That being said, don't post edits to your question as an answer; the best way to go is to either edit your question, or ask a new question if it is a completely separate issue. Happy coding!